# Gradle Build - Cannot invoke method (add) on null object

Tags: null

I have the following error and have been going in circles for a couple of days, would appreciate any thoughts.

This used to work in an earlier version of Gradle however now it has choked. I am currently using 4.1
Thanks.

Cannot invoke method (add) on null object

```
    productFlavors {
    create("armv7") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("${basedir}/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a")
```

Here are the full listings ;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def basedir = projectDir.absolutePath


android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
productFlavors {
    create("armv7") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("${basedir}/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a")
        String libsDir = "${basedir}/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/"
        ndk.ldLibs.addAll([
                libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_core.a",
                libsDir + "libtbb.a",
                libsDir + "liblibtiff.a",
                libsDir + "liblibpng.a",
                libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a",
                libsDir + "liblibjasper.a",
                libsDir + "libIlmImf.a",
        ])
    }
}
ndk {
    moduleName = "biocore"
    stl = "gnustl_shared"

    cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
    cppFlags.add("-frtti")
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")

    cppFlags.add("-I${basedir}/src/main/headers".toString())
    cppFlags.add("-iquote${basedir}/src/main/jni".toString())

    ldLibs.addAll(["android","log","atomic","z"])
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled = false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
    }
}
}

dependencies {
}
```

And this is the project Gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
       url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    google()
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry it's too long ago for me to remember. If I do though I will add the info.

Comment: Alright, thank you.